# Set brackets before and after on every word in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to set curly brackets'{}' before and after on every word in string. for eg. `Hello everyone, is this my string.` and i want to change it into `{Hello} {everyone}, {is} {this} {my} {string}.`. For this purpose i split words using below code:

```
string a="Hello everyone is this my string.";
string[] words=a.Split(' ');
for(int i=0; i<words.Length; i++)
{
a=a.Replace(words[i],"{"+words[i]+"}");
}
```

code is working good but this replace `is` into `this`. and i got output like this `{Hello} {everyone}, {is} th{is} {my} {string}.`
How to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to be able to handle words that contain non-alphas, like `don't` and `O'Brien`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the particular behavior is the following line.

```
a=a.Replace(words[i],"{"+words[i]+"}");
```

String.Replace will replace all the occurrence of the particular string. So when you attempt to replace `is`, you would end up replacing the `is` substring in `this` as well.

You could do the following for getting the correct result.

```
var originalString ="Hello everyone is this my string.";
var words= Regex.Replace(originalString,@"\b[^ ]+\b",@"{$0}");
```

This would ensure the period character is taken care of as in the desired answer in OP.

Samples

```
Hello everyone is this my string.
{Hello} {everyone} {is} {this} {my} {string}.
```

```
Hello everyone, is this my string.
{Hello} {everyone}, {is} {this} {my} {string}.
```

Comment: Wouldn't this include commas and periods as part of the words? In the question the comma and period in the text are outside the brackets.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Thanks for pointing out, have updated the answer.